# I am not able to route through the link

Tags: angular

I am stuck at a very simple issue,not sure what's going wrong. I want to route to user component when anyone click on the value on users component.Attached the Image below to check on this. I have added user route also ,not sure whether it is not able to take

This is my app.module.ts class where my routes are

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule,Routes} from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import {AngularFireModule} from  'angularfire2';
import { UsersComponent } from './components/users/users.component';
import {FirebaseService} from './services/firebase.service';
import { AngularFireAuthModule ,AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule,AngularFireDatabase,FirebaseListObservable } from "angularfire2/database-deprecated";
import { UserComponent } from './components/user/user.component'; 




const appRoutes:Routes=[
  {
path:'' ,component:HomeComponent},
{path:'about',component:AboutComponent},
{path:'user/:id',component:UserComponent},

{path:'users',component:UsersComponent}

]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    UserComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [FirebaseService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is my users.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import{FirebaseService} from '../../services/firebase.service';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent  {


public users1:Array<Object>=[];
public valid:Boolean = false;;



  constructor(private firebaseservice:FirebaseService) {

    this.firebaseservice.getusers().subscribe(users1=>{
   let tempuser= users1[0]

for(let Object in tempuser){
  this.users1.push(tempuser[Object])

}

console.log(users1);

    });
   }




}
```

This is my users.component.html code''

```
<ul class="list-group" >
  <li class='list-group-item' *ngFor='let user of users1'>

   <a routerLink="['/user/'+user.$key]">  {{user.city}} </a>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

This is my firebase.service.ts class

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from "angularfire2/database-deprecated"; 

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {

users:FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  constructor(private af:AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getusers()
  {

    this.users=this.af.list('/users') as FirebaseListObservable<Users[]>
    return this.users;

  }



}
interface Users{

 $key?:string;
  title?:string;
type?:string;
image?:string;
city?:string;
owner?:string;
bedrooms?:string;
path?:string;
price?:string;

  }
```

Data Image
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaAKl.png)

Comment: Try `<a [routerLink]="['/user/'+user.$key]">  {{user.city}} </a>`. Notice the square brackets around `routerLink` attribute

Comment: oh i am feeling so stupid ,thanku .. it works ..not sure when did i miss that

Comment: Do not feel stupid. Unfocusing/scattered attention happens to all of us very often.

Comment: @Igor Soloydenko  one more issue is when i am trying to click it redirects to the user page but in the url key is not going  ['/user/'+user.$key]"  not sure this is correct way or not   link 1st->   https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B04tF7QbpTmCT2xRYlZ3VkJXdGM   link 2nd->https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B04tF7QbpTmCME95Vk52cWE3RUk

Comment: now instead of undefined ,null is showing in the url  link->https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B04tF7QbpTmCNTROT0FCR1ZteUU

Comment: $key is the key id of the user which i implemented in interface   getusers()
  {

    this.users=this.af.list('/users') as FirebaseListObservable<Users[]>
    return this.users;
    
  }

  

}
interface Users{

 $key?:string;
  title?:string;
type?:string;
image?:string;
city?:string;
owner?:string;
bedrooms?:string;
path?:string;
price?:string;
    }      link -->https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B04tF7QbpTmCOTdXRkhLNlNTRVk

Comment: edited  ,could you check now and help me

Comment: Can you highlight for me where are the users' `$key` s in your **data**? I don't see the field declared in the interface. But in your browser I don't see any user to have a $key value